# Conversion failed when converting the varchar value '"&Variable.Text&"' to data type int

Tags: sql, sql-server

In using this revised query, I am finding that I am now getting a conversion error when trying to apply the variable to my WHERE statements. Thanks for any help on this.

I have tried to put in the actual value that the variable holds and the query works perfectly, however when trying to replace the number (as I have done with the piece of code after "AND" it comes up with the error below. The data is essentially a combination of year and month and reads 2018011, 2018012, 2019001, 2019002 etc...

```
Select *
 From (
        SELECT A_TABLE.BU_CODE
              ,A_TABLE.ACCNT_CODE 
              ,A_TABLE.PERIOD
              ,A_TABLE.REPORT_AMT
              ,A_TABLE.TREFERENCE
              ,A_TABLE.DESCRIPTN
              ,A_TABLE.ANAL_T0
              ,'A' MEASURE 
        FROM  A_TABLE WHERE (A_TABLE.ANAL_T0 = 'B80' AND A_TABLE.PERIOD BETWEEN 2019001 AND '"&Variable.text&"')
        UNION ALL
        SELECT B_TABLE.BU_CODE
              ,B_TABLE.ACCNT_CODE
              ,B_TABLE.PERIOD
              ,B_TABLE.REPORT_AMT
              ,B_TABLE.TREFERENCE
              ,B_TABLE.DESCRIPTN
              ,B_TABLE.ANAL_T0  
             ,'B' MEASURE 
        FROM B_TABLE WHERE (B_TABLE.ANAL_T0 = 'B80' AND B_TABLE.PERIOD BETWEEN 2019001 AND '"&Variable.text&"')
      ) src
PIVOT ( SUM(REPORT_AMT) FOR MEASURE IN ([A], [B])  ) AS PivotTable
```

I get this error message when I run the above.

> Conversion failed when converting the varchar value
>   '"&Variable.Text&"' to data type int.

I have now tried to add this but get the error further up.

```
Declare @CBal Int
Set @CBal = '"&Variable.Text&"'
```

The software this is in - in a simple SELECT FROM WHERE query I can use the above and it works e.g. this has no issue

```
SELECT * FROM A_TABLE WHERE A_TABLE.PERIOD BETWEEN '"&Variable.Text&"' AND '"&Variable.Text&"'
```

Comment: Sorry - SQL-Server, I will adjust the tag

Comment: The error seems clear, `&Variable.Text&` is indeed not an integer

Comment: Sounds like `&Variable.text&` comes from wherever you construct your query (VB or something, perhaps?). Share the code that constructs the query (and look into parameterization, while you're at it).

Comment: `A_TABLE.PERIOD BETWEEN 2019001 AND '"&Variable.text&"'` doesn't make any sense. If `Variable.text` is coming from an application though, you should be parametrising it, not injecting the value.

Comment: The variable is generated in a tool called Application Studio - it basically allows me to create variables to use for filters, options, entries in OLAP cubes etc... this variable is simply taking a selection and assigning it to this variable.

Comment: Thank you - I need to work out how this parameterising works it seems ... it was strange it worked in a simpler piece of code.

Comment: What is the data type of `A_TABLE.PERIOD`? `2019001` is seen as an int and `'"&Variable.Text&"'` as a string, so when you use them in one "between" expression, the string will be converted to int (which fails). Your last sample may raise no complaints, because you test between two strings (alphabetically) - I guess it doesn't really find records however because you probably don't have the text `"&Variable.Text&"` in that column.

Answer (score 0):

First you should put date filter inside single inverted comma, that is '2019001'. Second, '"&Variable.Text&"' this should be date format not string.

If you want to pass a variable for second date than use the correct syntax.